# How to allow all characters but number from input

Tags: javascript, html

At the moment, I have an input. I am allowed to enter any characters, even special characters, no digits.

What I've tried so far is to setup a keydown and a keyup event.

```
ng-keydown="vm.preventNumberInput($event)"
ng-onkeyup="vm.preventNumberInput($event)"

vm.preventNumberInput = function (e) {
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58 || keyCode > 95 && keyCode < 107) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

This works okay, but it prevents me from adding special characters like !@#%^&*.

May I ask how do I allow characters from being entered into my input that aren't digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the event's `key` property to get the pressed key. If it matches `\d` (a digit), call `preventDefault`:

```
vm.preventNumberInput = function (e) {
    if (/\d/.test(e.key)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Any characters other than digits will be allowed.

(note that the `keyCode` and `which` properties are deprecated, and should be avoided when possible)